# Vuejs Fetch Request returns data but attributes assignments don't work

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I am playing around with Vuejs in our project. I have used the same technique in my other project and its working. But here I am not able to assign the data return by the fetch request to a json resource.

When I try to access data returned in then and put it in alert it does gives me the data objects. but I want to assign it to my data attribute packages array.

Here is my component code

```
<template>
 <div id="packages">
    <div class='radio' v-for="package in packages">
        <label>
            <input type='radio' name='packageradio' v-bind:value="package.id">{{ package.quantity }}
            <span id='price-tag'>{{ package.price }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            packages:[]
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.fetchPackages();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchPackages: function(){
            fetch('/die-cut/size/4/packages')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(function(res){
                    alert("i am hit");
                    this.packages = res;
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the api:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"quantity": 50,
"price": 400,
"saving": 100,
"size_id": 4,
"sticker_id": 2,
"created_at": "2018-02-21 17:48:46",
"updated_at": "2018-02-21 17:48:46"
},
{
"id": 2,
"quantity": 100,
"price": 900,
"saving": 100,
"size_id": 4,
"sticker_id": 2,
"created_at": "2018-02-21 17:50:43",
"updated_at": "2018-02-21 17:50:43"
}
]
```

Comment: Moreover, I get the i am hit alert,, That means the asynchronous request is perfect. And I also had printed the response objects in alert() but its not assigning the response to packages

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: Please read the code, what i am doing is a request to an api that gives me json response.  then I want to assign that array of data to my packages data attribute. simple i am getting the response successful even within then() i have got the correct value as alert(res[0].price); and it gives me the data. but the target is to assign it to packages attribute which i will bind to my html

Comment: So, `<h1>{{ packages[0].price }}</h1>` should work fine.

Comment: Check the code now, it is not actually updating the packages after the response.

Answer (score 0):

The data for packages should be working fine. The problem I see in your code is with the following html:

```
<label>
   <input type='radio' name='packageradio' v-bind:value="package.id">
   {{ package.quantity }}
   <span id='price-tag'>{{ package.price }}</span>
</label>
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) for the label element:

> `label` can permit the [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content), but no descendant label elements. No labelable elements other than the labeled control are allowed.

So, in your code having `input` a flow content is the key issue.

---

The issue with your code is:

```
.then(function(res){
   alert("i am hit");
   this.packages = res; 
   // this isn't referenced to the vue instance from the function scope
 })
```

Replace it with this:

```
.then(res => { // access parent scope
   alert("i am hit");
   this.packages = res; // now, this will access the vue instance
 })
```

Comment: that's why i also tried only <h1>{{ packages}}</h1> but its showing nothing

Comment: not at all. I mentioned twice, I am getting the control into then which means the request has been successful can even print the data in then but assignment is not working for htis project. Have been successful in doing it in another project.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I have checked in the created lifecycle hooks this is pointing to the vue instance. But in methods functions it is empty that is the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

I think its to do with your this keyword so, either use the ES5 syntax or do some thing like this

```
fetchPackages: function(){
       var vm = this
        fetch('/die-cut/size/4/packages')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(function(res){
                alert("i am hit");
                vm.packages = res;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Or off course you can go ahead and do something like this,

```
fetchPackages(){
        fetch('/die-cut/size/4/packages')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
                alert("i am hit");
                this.packages = res;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Comment: and there is no difference if you assign it to a variable or do it directly both are not working for me

Comment: and yes i have checked this is empty in the methods functions

Comment: its quite strange, when i tried to check the this in created life cycle hook it is pointing to vue instance and in methods it don't

Comment: I have checked again this is now pointing to vue instance but attribute assignment now dont work