# My component data is not reactive in methods while reactive in lifecycle hook created

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vuejs in my project, been trying it for hours but not working. I have applied the same technique with my other project and that is working. The packages is changed locally, but the data attribute packages remains empty even after a successful return of data by my api

```
<script>
    export default {
        name:'packages',
        data(){
            return {
                packages: []
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.fetchPackages();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchPackages() {
                fetch('/die-cut/size/4/packages')
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(res => {
                        this.packages = res;
                        alert(this.packages);
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The component name is packages and the data item is packages. That shouldn't be a problem, but it might be worth changing a name to check.

Comment: have tried a message data attribute as well. But no luck

Comment: The alert happens and indicates some values?

Comment: Yes, it give me the updated packages array but the actual packages data attribute is not updated

Comment: *but the actual packages data attribute is not updated* -> how are you telling that? Your code is ok.

Comment: That is the pain point of mine, have been doing it in other two projects, but here it is the issue. Don't know why!

Comment: I'm asking how can you tell that it is not being updated? Where are you seeing it not being updated?

Comment: i have bind the packages to my html and that is not being changed

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/why-i-can-not-set-data-in-my-component-and-getting-cannot-set-property-of-undefined/4598/2 have tried the self as well but not working. Although the ecma script style => points to the parent this and working in my two other projects but this is making me mad

Comment: can you have a look at it through teamviewer will take your 2 minutes

Comment: You are using arrow functions, the problem in that forum post doesn't apply to you. But, again, it must be something else, your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/50wL7mdz/177627/

Comment: Seriously I don't know why it is not working on this project. I have used the same technique in my other projects and that is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166633/discussion-between-haider-ali-and-acdcjunior).

Comment: Try adding more context to the question, more code. The code that uses this component you posted. The template that is not updating, etc.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217746/vuejs-fetch-request-returns-data-but-attributes-assignments-dont-work/

Answer (score 0):

I was adding the script twice on the page and that was causing the issue, the master layout file already have the vuejs included, and I added the script on the view that is derived from master layout. When I removed it from the view as the master layout already have it included it worked! Strange